# Dynamically assign values to object properties with keyof through bracket notation (Typescript TS2322)

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to assign something to a object property accessed by its key using bracket notation?

The following example results in two typescript errors. The typeguard does not seem to remember its type. Is there a way I could work around this, without casting to any?

```js
type A = {
  b: string;
  c: number;
};
function test(a: A) {
  Object.keys(a).forEach((key: keyof A) => {
    if (typeof a[key] === 'string') {
      const aKey: string = a[key]; // <-- TS2322: Type string | number is not assignable to type string
      a[key] = ''                  // <-- TS2322: Type string is not assignable to type never
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This is [ms/TS#32693](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693); you could try refactoring to make things much more generic, but I don't know that it's worth it to you, since it'll be fragile and ultimately more annoying than just using a type assertion or "casting" to any.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: So there is no better way than using a type assertion like `(a as any)[key] = a[key]`?

Comment: There's no better way than *some* kind of type loosening.  The closest I can get to having this work is [this version](https://tsplay.dev/wgG24w), and even that involves a custom type guard function to convince the compiler that `a` can be treated as a `Record<typeof key, string>`.  So, shall I write up the answer or is there still something missing?

Comment: Hmm, I am thinking about this solution. Now the `aa` variable (pointing to the `a` object) says that all its properties are strings. That is more specific, however `a` has string and number properties. So an `any` cast might be more correct/descriptive than asserting `Record<typeof key, string>`?

Comment: No, `aa` says that all properties at keys of type `K` are `string`s, which is true if `acceptsString(a, key)` is `true`. So, shall I write up an answer or is there still something missing?

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks, this is better than casting to any. If you could create an answer of this, that would be great!